# Parallel Recursive Grep While Omitting String

Tags: linux, grep, parallelism

## Problem

I cannot perform a recursive parallel zgrep while also omitting a string from the results.

I am zgrepping through about 640GB of compressed firewall logs and almost %30 of the lines have the string "Duplicate SYN" (which i am trying to omit)

## Recursive Parallel Zgrep (without omitting a string) - success

I am able to successfully perform a parallel recurse grep like this

```
find /var/logs/syslog -name \* -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 36 zgrep -f foo.txt > /tmp/bar.txt
```

Content of foo.txt:

```
10\.10\.0\.28
10\.10\.3\.41
10\.10\.0\.46
10\.10\.5\.47
10\.11\.0\.48
10\.10\.0\.49
10\.144\.41\.145
10\.122\.41\.241
```

### Example Output

```
Apr 18 01:39:33 ASAFW01 : %ASA-4-419002: Duplicate TCP SYN from inside:10.10.0.28/61763 to inside:10.122.41.241/8443 with different initial sequence number
Apr 18 01:39:33 ASAFW01 : %ASA-4-419002: Duplicate TCP SYN from inside:10.10.0.28/61763 to inside:10.122.41.241/8443 with different initial sequence number
May 31 02:58:46 ASAFW01 : %ASA-6-302014: Teardown TCP connection 461681145 for DMZ_EXP_INSIDE:10.122.41.241/7400 to inside:10.5.91.50/30378 duration 0:00:00 bytes 0 Failover primary closed
May 31 02:58:47 ASAFW01 : %ASA-6-302013: Built outbound TCP connection 1962428108 for DMZ_EXP_INSIDE:10.122.41.241/7400 (10.122.41.241/7400) to inside:10.11.0.48/33990 (10.11.0.48/33990)
May 31 02:58:47 ASAFW01 : %ASA-6-302014: Teardown TCP connection 1962428108 for DMZ_EXP_INSIDE:10.122.41.241/7400 to inside:10.11.0.48/33990 duration 0:00:00 bytes 3188 TCP Reset-O from DMZ_EXP_INSIDE
May 31 02:58:49 ASAFW01 : %ASA-6-106015: Deny TCP (no connection) from 10.11.0.48/35976 to 10.122.41.241/7400 flags RST  on interface inside
May 31 02:58:49 ASAFW01 : %ASA-6-106015: Deny TCP (no connection) from 10.11.0.48/35976 to 10.122.41.241/7400 flags RST  on interface inside
```

### Output I want to omit

```
Apr 18 01:39:33 ASAFW01 : %ASA-4-419002: Duplicate TCP SYN from inside:10.10.0.28/61763 to inside:10.122.41.241/8443 with different initial sequence number
Apr 18 01:39:33 ASAFW01 : %ASA-4-419002: Duplicate TCP SYN from inside:10.10.0.28/61763 to inside:10.122.41.241/8443 with different initial sequence number
```

### Ideas

- Modify foo.txt to use a regular expression that omits the word "Duplicate" (not sure how to do this)
- Recursively remove all lines that contain the word "Duplicate" in all 640GB of gzipped log files (using sed?)

## Recursive Parallel Zgrep (with omitting a string) - failure

However when I attempt to exclude something from the results I get an error.

Command that causes an error:

```
find /var/logs/syslog -name \* -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 36 zgrep -f foo.txt -v Duplicate > /tmp/bar.txt

gzip: Duplicate.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Duplicate.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Duplicate.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Duplicate.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Duplicate.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: Duplicate.gz: No such file or directory
```

Comment: can you create two very small sample files (no need compressed, plain needed for testing) - and show what you expect from the grep command? I don't think you can specify both a positive search string and a negative one in same command.. you'll have to pipe output of one to the other, or may be possible with PCRE (but expensive, piping may still be faster)

Comment: try `grep -f foo.txt ip.txt | grep -v Duplicate` .. also, you can remove all the backslashes from foo.txt and use `grep -Ff foo.txt ip.txt | grep -v Duplicate`.. I would further suggest to use `grep -wFf foo.txt ip.txt | grep -v Duplicate` to avoid `10.10.0.28` matching something like `10.10.0.282` or `210.10.0.28`

Comment: I do not want to pipe it in to a "-v" as i don't have space to handle the temp file that will balloon as a result of including the "duplicate" lines

Comment: I'd modify foo.txt to have `(?!.*Duplicate)` starting each line and have zgrep use `-P` so that the negative lookahead works.  Also, Sundeep's got a good point about substrings... might use `\b` at the start and end of each IP to ensure there's a word boundary.

Comment: @stevesliva when i used -P i got the error message "grep: the -P option only supports a single pattern"

Comment: @brakertech: damn.  This is why it wasn't an answer... because I didn't test extensively. That said, you can combine it all into one regex. `(?!.*Duplicate)\b(10\.10\.0\.28|10\.10\.3\.41|10\.10\.0\.46|10\.10\.5\.47|10\.11\.0\.48|10\.10\.0\.49|10\.144\.41\.145|10\.122\.41\.241)\b`

Comment: I don't know what happens..I'm guessing, but shouldn't memory not be a concern as `grep -v` doesn't have to wait for entire result of prior command in the pipeline.. so, it will process based on whenever it gets a chance and all processed line will keep getting written to disk..

Comment: also, another suggestion would be to use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) - you wouldn't need xargs and rg is very likely to be much faster than zgrep/grep.. and `rg -P` allows multiple patterns from file unlike GNU grep

Comment: @stevesliva thanks for the hint.  I had to modify your solution only slightly and it worked

    ```find /var/logs/syslog -name \* -print0 |  xargs -0 -n 1 -P 36 zgrep -P '^(?:(?!Duplicate).)*\b(10\.10\.0\.28|10\.10\.3\.41|10\.10\.0\.46|10\.10\.5\.47|10\.11\.0\.48|10\.10\.0\.49|10\.144\.41\.145|10\.122\.41\.241)\b$'```

Comment: @stevesliva can you post the answer so i can give you credit?

Comment: I'm actually surprised that you have a `$` at the end of the regex.  Doesn't seem like it would work with the input.  I find myself arriving back at what I first commented for the minimal regex... did your output change to have the IP address at the end of the line?

Comment: `-name \*` is useless.  Terms in a `find` command line are exclusions, and `-name \*` says to exclude files whose name doesn’t match `*` — but, of course, `*` matches everything, so `-name \*` excludes nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to *write* this additional condition is simply to pipe your output through another invocation of `grep` before writing to the file:

```
find /var/logs/syslog -name \* -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 36 zgrep -f foo.txt | grep -v Duplicate > /tmp/bar.txt
```

The performance of doing this in a separate single-threaded process will depend on how many records are being returned by your search. If the number of lines matching your initial search is only a small subset of your 640GB of logs, it shouldn't be an issue.

Since the underlying question is also partly about optimizing this search overall, I'll note that there are two big additional enhancements you can make:

1. Use fixed strings rather than regular expressions for your grep search terms -- remove the backslashes from your pattern file and add the `-F` switch to zgrep. (The `-w` switch to only match whole words would also likely be a good idea.) Searching for literal strings is far faster than searching for regular expressions.
2. If your system's locale uses UTF-8 but your data set is only ASCII, set `LC_ALL=C` in the command's environment. The search will go much faster working within the 128-character ASCII set than it will in the ~1000-times-larger UTF-8 character set.

Comment: Using the output from `xargs -P` is dangerous due to line mixing: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Non-atomic_writes_with_xargs_-P

Comment: @OleTange: Your comment belongs on the question, because the OP is already using the output from `xargs -P`.  Dan is just building on the command in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU Parallel you can do:

```
find /var/logs/syslog -name \* -print0 |
  parallel --lb -0 'zgrep -f foo.txt {} | grep -v Duplicate' > /tmp/bar.txt
```

Opposite `xargs -P` using the output from GNU Parallel is guaranteed not to mix lines (as per mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Non-atomic_writes_with_xargs_-P).